# Ruby on Rails bad URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm installed postgresql onto the computer, and it seems to work fine for the computer, but when I run this:

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

it gives this error message

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rbL is deprecated, please use Fiddle:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:176:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?)
: postgres:///zacks-pc\zack holbrook (URI::InvalidURIError)
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:211:in `parse'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:747:in `parse'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/actie_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:69:in `connection_url_o_hash'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/actie_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:41:in `block in resolv_string_connection'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/actie_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:40:in `fetch'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/actie_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:40:in `resolve_string_onnection'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/actie_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:32:in `spec'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/actie_record/connection_handling.rb:39:in `establish_connection'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/actie_record/railtie.rb:176:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/actve_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/actve_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/actve_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/actve_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/actve_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/actie_record/base.rb:322:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/actie_record/base.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.1/lib/rspe/rails/extensions/active_record/base.rb:19:in `<module:Extensions>'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.1/lib/rspe/rails/extensions/active_record/base.rb:4:in `<module:Rails>'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.1/lib/rspe/rails/extensions/active_record/base.rb:2:in `<module:RSpec>'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.1/lib/rspe/rails/extensions/active_record/base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/actve_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/actve_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/actve_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/actve_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.1/lib/rspe/rails/extensions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/actve_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/actve_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/actve_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/actve_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.1/lib/rspe/rails.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/actve_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/actve_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/actve_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/actve_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from c:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:4:in `<top (equired)>'
    from c:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.b:1:in `require'
    from c:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.b:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

What is the URI, and do i need to change it?
I am using windows, and am new to Ruby on Rails, any help would be appreciated, thanks!
The site is on Github: https://github.com/ioniz4tion/sample_app/tree/postgre

database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: cnh_development
  pool: 5
  username: cnh
  password: my_password

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: cnh_test
  pool: 5
  username: cnh
  password: my_password

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: cnh_production
  pool: 5
  username: cnh
  password: my_password
```

Comment: Can you post your spec_helper and static_pages_spec files?

Comment: I have the site on github, https://github.com/ioniz4tion/sample_app/tree/postgre will that work?

Comment: Can you post the database.yml file

Comment: @StianS Ya, I just edited it in

Comment: Looks like You've got a DATABASE_URL environment variable set somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your postgres config has a problem. In the message your provided:

```
postgres:///zacks-pc\zack holbrook
```

This looks like the kind of url Postgres use to identify a database, but the mix of forward and backward slash (/ vs ) looks weird to me. Look at your database config, it probable comes from there.

Answer (score 0):

In you database.yml file try some like this if your working on your local file

```
login: &login
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  username: postgres
  password: yourpassword!
  pool: 5
  encoding: unicode


development:
    database: dbname
    <<: *login

test:
   database: dbname
   <<: *login

production:
  database: dbname
  <<: *login
```